# Borel $\sigma$-algebras on the Skorohod space $D[0,1]$

Tags: measure-theory, skorohod-space

On the Skorohod space $D[0,1]$ of cadlag functions one usually considers either the uniform norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ or the $J_1$-metric $\varrho$. I was wondering whether both generate the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra:

It is widely known that

$$\varrho(f,g) \leq \|f-g\|_{\infty},$$

i.e. the $J_1$-topology is coarser, and this implies in particular that the corresponding Borel $\sigma$-algebras satisfy the relation

$$\mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\varrho)) \subseteq \mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}). \tag{1}$$

On the other hand, one can show that $\mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\varrho))=\sigma(\pi_t;t \in [0,1])$ where $\pi_t(f) :=f(t)$, $t \in [0,1]$, denotes the natural projection (see e.g. Billingsley, Convergence of Probability Measures, Theorem 12.5). Now for any countable dense set $T \subseteq [0,1]$, $1 \in T$, we have

$$B_{(D[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})}[0,1] := \{f \in D[0,1], \|f\|_{\infty} \leq 1\} = \bigcap_{t \in T} \{f \in D[0,1]; \pi_t f \in [-1,1]\} \in \sigma(\pi_t;t \in [0,1]) \stackrel{(1)}{=} \mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\varrho)).$$

by the right-continuity of the functions. A similar argumentation shows that $B_{(D[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty})}[f,\varepsilon] \in \mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\varrho))$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, $f \in D[0,1]$. Hence,

$$\mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\varrho)) \supseteq \mathcal{B}((D[0,1],\|\cdot\|_{\infty}),$$

and this means that both Borel-$\sigma$-algebras are equal. Is there anything wrong about this argumentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You show that the ball-sigma-algebra of the uniform topology coincides with the Skorohod-Borel-sigma-algebra. However, the Borel-sigma-algebra of the uniform topology is strictly
larger (that can happen because the uniform topology is not separable here).
See chapt. 15 of Billingsley's book for more on this.

Answer (score 2):

the Borel sigma algebra (wrt the uniform norm) is not generated by balls.
since the uniform norm turns the Banach space into a non-separable one.
(i.e. you can not write every Open set U as countable union of balls!)

Regards,

Chiu